# How do I represent multiple host data into a single JSON or a table?

Tags: json, ansible

I am getting the v_data from 2 different hosts: HOST-1, HOST-2.

```
TASK [Print v_data] **************************************************************************************************
ok: [HOST-1] => {
    "v_data": [
        {
            "vrf": "vrf-11",
            "ip": "10.10.10.1",
            "policy": "RP-11",
            "max-pref": "15",
            "thresh": "15%"
        },
        {
            "vrf": "vrf-12",
            "ip": "10.10.10.2",
            "policy": "RP-12",
            "max-pref": "15",
            "thresh": "15%"
        }
    ]
}
ok: [HOST-2] => {
    "v_data": [
        {
            "vrf": "vrf-21",
            "ip": "20.20.20.1",
            "policy": "RP-21",
            "max-pref": "15",
            "thresh": "15%"
        },
        {
            "vrf": "vrf-22",
            "ip": "20.20.20.2",
            "policy": "RP-22",
            "max-pref": "25",
            "thresh": "25%"
        }
    ]
}
```

I get the data into a table format if I convert it into a table (single host).

[image]

And I am doing the below to get the data into a singe json/table:

```
- name: Get v_data
  shell: echo "{{ v_data }}"
  register: v_data
  loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"
  vars:
    vd: "{{ hostvars[item]['v_data'] }}"

- name: Create data structure
  set_fact:
    host_data: "{{ host_data | default([]) + [{'host': item.item, 'v_data': item.stdout | from_json }] }}"
  with_items: "{{ v_data.results }}"

- name: Print data structure
  debug:
    var: host_data
```

But I want to get the data as below and hence I can convert the same to a CSV or a table as below:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "host": "HOST-1",
      "v_data": [
        {
          "vrf": "vrf-11",
          "ip": "10.10.10.1",
          "policy": "RP-11",
          "max-pref": "15",
          "thresh": "15%"
        },
        {
          "vrf": "vrf-12",
          "ip": "10.10.10.2",
          "policy": "RP-12",
          "max-pref": "15",
          "thresh": "15%"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "host": "HOST-1",
      "v_data": [
        {
          "vrf": "vrf-21",
          "ip": "20.20.20.1",
          "policy": "RP-21",
          "max-pref": "15",
          "thresh": "15%"
        },
        {
          "vrf": "vrf-22",
          "ip": "20.20.20.2",
          "policy": "RP-22",
          "max-pref": "25",
          "thresh": "25%"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

[image]

Even if I have hosts, `HOST-1, HOST-2, .....HOST-n`,
how to represent/convert the data from each `inventory_hostname` and combine/merge to a single JSON in order to further convert to a table.
not sure I can use the term combine/merge. final output should be as shown in `data` and screenshot

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell. You can debug intermediate variables in the task to better understand the process but  the different steps and corresponding variable names should be enough for the first idea.

Note: I created the following fake `inventories/demo/hosts.yml` inventory to run against your example data:

```yaml
all:
  vars:
    ansible_connection: local
  hosts:
    HOST-1:
      "v_data": [
        {
            "vrf": "vrf-11",
            "ip": "10.10.10.1",
            "policy": "RP-11",
            "max-pref": "15",
            "thresh": "15%"
        },
        {
            "vrf": "vrf-12",
            "ip": "10.10.10.2",
            "policy": "RP-12",
            "max-pref": "15",
            "thresh": "15%"
        }
      ]
    HOST-2:
      "v_data": [
        {
            "vrf": "vrf-21",
            "ip": "20.20.20.1",
            "policy": "RP-21",
            "max-pref": "15",
            "thresh": "15%"
        },
        {
            "vrf": "vrf-22",
            "ip": "20.20.20.2",
            "policy": "RP-22",
            "max-pref": "25",
            "thresh": "25%"
        }
      ]
```

Using the above, the `merge_json.yml` demo playbook:

```yaml
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:
    - name: Print v_data
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: v_data

    - name: print a single json containing all data as per OP requirements
      vars:
        list_of_hosts: "{{ ansible_play_hosts }}"
        list_of_v_data: "{{ ansible_play_hosts | map('extract', hostvars, 'v_data') }}"
        data_dict: "{{ dict(list_of_hosts | zip(list_of_v_data)) }}"
        data: "{{ data_dict | dict2items('host', 'v_data') }}"
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        var: v_data_list
      run_once: true
```

returns:

```
$ ansible-playbook -i inventories/demo/ merge_json.yaml 

PLAY [all] *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Print v_data] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [HOST-1] => {
    "v_data": [
        {
            "ip": "10.10.10.1",
            "max-pref": "15",
            "policy": "RP-11",
            "thresh": "15%",
            "vrf": "vrf-11"
        },
        {
            "ip": "10.10.10.2",
            "max-pref": "15",
            "policy": "RP-12",
            "thresh": "15%",
            "vrf": "vrf-12"
        }
    ]
}
ok: [HOST-2] => {
    "v_data": [
        {
            "ip": "20.20.20.1",
            "max-pref": "15",
            "policy": "RP-21",
            "thresh": "15%",
            "vrf": "vrf-21"
        },
        {
            "ip": "20.20.20.2",
            "max-pref": "25",
            "policy": "RP-22",
            "thresh": "25%",
            "vrf": "vrf-22"
        }
    ]
}

TASK [print a single json containing all data as per OP requirements] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [HOST-1] => {
    "data": [
        {
            "host": "HOST-1",
            "v_data": [
                {
                    "ip": "10.10.10.1",
                    "max-pref": "15",
                    "policy": "RP-11",
                    "thresh": "15%",
                    "vrf": "vrf-11"
                },
                {
                    "ip": "10.10.10.2",
                    "max-pref": "15",
                    "policy": "RP-12",
                    "thresh": "15%",
                    "vrf": "vrf-12"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "host": "HOST-2",
            "v_data": [
                {
                    "ip": "20.20.20.1",
                    "max-pref": "15",
                    "policy": "RP-21",
                    "thresh": "15%",
                    "vrf": "vrf-21"
                },
                {
                    "ip": "20.20.20.2",
                    "max-pref": "25",
                    "policy": "RP-22",
                    "thresh": "25%",
                    "vrf": "vrf-22"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
HOST-1                     : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
HOST-2                     : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the inventory

```ini
shell> cat hosts
host_1
host_2
host_3
```

and the *host_vars* with simplified variables *v_data* for testing

```bash
shell> tree host_vars
host_vars
├── host_1
│   └── vdata.yml
├── host_2
│   └── vdata.yml
└── host_3
    └── vdata.yml

3 directories, 3 files
```

```yaml
shell> find host_vars -type f | xargs cat
v_data: data for host_1
v_data: data for host_3
v_data: data for host_2
```

- The playbook

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    data: "{{ dict(hostvars|dict2items|
                   json_query('[].[key, value.v_data]')) }}"

  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        v_data: "{{ v_data }}"
    - debug:
        var: data
      run_once: true
```

combines the data into a single dictionary

```yaml
  data:
    host_1: data for host_1
    host_2: data for host_2
    host_3: data for host_3
```

- Fit the query to your needs. For example,

```yaml
  data: "{{ dict(hostvars|dict2items|
                 json_query('[].[key, {vdata: value.v_data}]')) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  data:
    host_1:
      vdata: data for host_1
    host_2:
      vdata: data for host_2
    host_3:
      vdata: data for host_3
```

- To display the dictionary in JSON use the filter *to_json* or *to_nice_json*

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          data:
            {{ data|to_nice_json(indent=2)|indent(2) }}
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    data:
      {
        "host_1": {
          "vdata": "data for host_1"
        },
        "host_2": {
          "vdata": "data for host_2"
        },
        "host_3": {
          "vdata": "data for host_3"
        }
      }
```

- You can select the values only

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: |
          data:
            {{ data.values()|list|to_nice_json(indent=2)|indent(2) }}
```

gives

```yaml
  msg: |-
    data:
      [
        {
          "vdata": "data for host_1"
        },
        {
          "vdata": "data for host_2"
        },
        {
          "vdata": "data for host_3"
        }
      ]
```

---

**Create csv files**

Given the data

```yaml
shell> find host_vars -type f | xargs cat
v_data: [
        {
            "ip": "10.10.10.1",
            "max-pref": "15",
            "policy": "RP-11",
            "thresh": "15%",
            "vrf": "vrf-11"
        },
        {
            "ip": "10.10.10.2",
            "max-pref": "15",
            "policy": "RP-12",
            "thresh": "15%",
            "vrf": "vrf-12"
        }
    ]
v_data: [
        {
            "ip": "30.30.30.1",
            "max-pref": "15",
            "policy": "RP-31",
            "thresh": "15%",
            "vrf": "vrf-31"
        },
        {
            "ip": "30.30.30.2",
            "max-pref": "25",
            "policy": "RP-32",
            "thresh": "35%",
            "vrf": "vrf-32"
        }
    ]
v_data: [
        {
            "ip": "20.20.20.1",
            "max-pref": "15",
            "policy": "RP-21",
            "thresh": "15%",
            "vrf": "vrf-21"
        },
        {
            "ip": "20.20.20.2",
            "max-pref": "25",
            "policy": "RP-22",
            "thresh": "25%",
            "vrf": "vrf-22"
        }
    ]
```

the play

```yaml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    data: "{{ dict(hostvars|dict2items|
                   json_query('[].[key, {vdata: value.v_data}]')) }}"
    keys: [ip, max-pref, policy, thresh, vrf]

  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        v_data: "{{ v_data }}"

    - copy:
        dest: /tmp/test/data.csv
        content: |
          host,{{ keys|join(',') }}
          {% for k,v in data.items() %}
          {% for i in v.vdata %}
          {{ k }},{{ keys|map('extract', i)|join(',') }}
          {% endfor %}
          {% endfor %}
      run_once: true
      delegate_to: localhost
```

will create the csv file

```bash
shell> cat /tmp/test/data.csv 
host,ip,max-pref,policy,thresh,vrf
host_1,10.10.10.1,15,RP-11,15%,vrf-11
host_1,10.10.10.2,15,RP-12,15%,vrf-12
host_2,20.20.20.1,15,RP-21,15%,vrf-21
host_2,20.20.20.2,25,RP-22,25%,vrf-22
host_3,30.30.30.1,15,RP-31,15%,vrf-31
host_3,30.30.30.2,25,RP-32,35%,vrf-32
```